# Why is openssl_pkey_new so much faster than gpg?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, gnupg

I am looking into asymmetric encryption with PHP.

In my preliminary tests I notice that `openssl_pkey_new` generates keys **MUCH** faster than `gpg --gen-keys` on the command line. In each case this is for RSA keys of the same length.

My first guess would be that the random number generation in the OpenSSL library is not as secure.

Is this the reason? And can I trust `openssl_pkey_new` to generate strong keys?

Comment: An Analysis of OpenSSL's Random Number Generator: http://eprint.iacr.org/2016/367

Comment: Thanks. What should I use instead, ideally staying within PHP 7 and not having to install any dependencies. (I'm open to ECC but can't seem to find a tidy out-of-the box solution).

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods for generating RSA key pairs. If you keep to the strict ANSI X9.31 requirements key generation will be rather slow.

Furthermore the speed of the primality test depends on fast operations over very large integers. The speed of those operations can differ significantly, an upgrade from Java 8 to Java 9 for instance will show you double the performance for 2048 bit keys.

Compared to that the random number generation should not matter too much, unless you run out of entropy to seed the random number generator from. Using `/dev/random/` directly could also cause trouble. But the primality tests likely uses a lot more time than the RNG.

Finally note that the time of RSA key pair generation depends on finding two primes of about half the key size. Finding primes takes an undeterministic amount of time - basically you can find them almost immediately or you can spend quite a bit of time finding a prime. Primes are distributed rather well, but the random starting point can be close to a prime or rather far away from one. You'd probably have to test a few thousand key pair generations to average things out.

All in all, the speed of the key pair generator doesn't tell you much about the quality of the random numbers or the resulting keys. The additional tests in ANSI X9.31 don't really matter much anymore.